# Entity Framework composite key issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting this issue when trying to use a composite key in Entity Framework

> Additional information: The properties expression 't => new
>   <>f__AnonymousType0 is not valid. The expression should represent a
>   property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.
>   When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't =>
>   new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With {
>   t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

The code is

```
 // Primary Key
 this.HasKey(t => new { t.ID, t.ID2, t.Version.Major, t.Version.Minor,  t.Version.Revision, t.Version.Build });
```

MODEL

```
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public short ID2 { get; set; }

  private VersionType m_Version;
  public VersionType Version
  {
     get
     {
        return m_Version;
     }
     set
     {
        SetProperty(ref m_Version, value, () => this.Version);
     }
  }



modelBuilder.ComplexType<VersionType>()
```

I believe its to do with declaring the Version class before the property (Major etc).

if so, is there anyway I can fix this?

Cheers

Comment: Could you please add the code for your model?

Comment: Thinking in terms of SQL relationships and tables, how can you set a key to be on a table when some of the data is in another table? IE. Version.*. Version is a Navigation property of `t` so SQL cannot create a key constraint on it.

Comment: @Tacoman667 I was thinking it was part of a Complex type, but we can only guess unless he posts the code

Comment: I believe that is right, like my assmuption states, I post the model

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147#What Complex types are VERY restrictive...

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I can't use version and must separate the properties indivudually

Comment: Is VersionType another entity Model stored in a table in SQL? I am guessing it is.

Comment: Actually its not, its just a class that holds the Major, minor etc etc

Comment: What version of EF are you using? And can you add your VersionType model definition?

Comment: 6.1

I have updated my question

Comment: Will using modelBuilder.Entity<VersionType>() by of any use?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this might help you from a previous SO question roughly the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5683788/78551 See how they define the models and the fluent api configuration.